# Can I search layer data in Mapbox?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Using Mapbox, is it possible to search the layer's data (i.e., building footprints. zoom to buildings with sq feet >2,000)? The more specific the help the better. Thank you

Comment: "The more specific the help the better." - can you provide a much more specific question: is this a layer from TileMill, Mapbox Studio, or in the Mapbox.com editor, or Mapbox GL...?

Comment: I guess my question is more: which tech stack to use to allow user to filter datasets on the fly. I have layers showing points and polygons. I want user to filter these based on a few options. I.e. show only states with >5 million people.